# BizTalk, enlist a web service with database transaction through WS-AT

Tags: biztalk

we expose a BizTalk web service, the web service then calls a database, sometimes the database took longer time, the data was changed though the web service time out, in this case, the caller thinks the call failed however the data is already changed. (e.g. the client account is already debited)

How to achieve the end to end transaction in this scenario, would enabling the WS-AT transaction helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do depending on requirements.

If all the caller requires is an acknowledgement that they have successfully send their request, you could have an orchestration that gives a OK response straight away, and calls the database afterwards.  If the transaction fails for some reason after this point you will either have to send a failure message internally, or a asynchronous failure message to the caller.

If you need a synchronous response after the update, you need to reduce the latency of the transaction.   Find out what is taking so long.  Things to look at the latency of the webservice to start up, the BizTalk process and the database.   There is usually things you can do to all three to reduce the latency of each of them.  That is a long topic so I won't go into details as yet.

Increase the time-out on the webservice.  This would probably also require the caller to increase the time-out on their end as well.

And no, I've been told that it is not possible to use WS-AT that way.
Also see [BizTalk 2009 : WS-AtomicTransaction Support](http://tutorial.wmlcloud.com/windows_server/BizTalk-2009---WS-AtomicTransaction-Support.aspx)

> The scope of the transaction is limited to a one-way receive port. When the receive location is bound to a request-response receive port, the Transactions section will be disabled. BizTalk will flow the WSAtomicTransaction request until the message has been committed to the Messagebox for processing.
>   Read more at http://tutorial.wmlcloud.com/windows_server/BizTalk-2009---WS-AtomicTransaction-Support.aspx#r5LtZ6ou1xmtoSTd.99

[image: WS-Atomic Transaction disabled on Request Response]

WS-Atomic Transaction disabled on Request Response port

Comment: thanks for sharing!! it is synchronize call in our case. increase the web service timeout is something we will do, but what if the case the SQL call times out, how to reply to the caller in that case?

Comment: Then you will probably need to cope with the caller resending the transaction and check to see if it has already been applied.